# How can my function take csv files as an input?

Tags: python, csv, xlrd

I need to take a csv file as a function argument and as an example code I have:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv
import xlrd


def supermarket(filename):
dictionary = {}
with open(filename, newline='') as filename:
    read_csv = csv.reader(filename, delimiter=',')
    for row in read_csv:
        dictionary += row[0]
        dictionary[row[0]] = row[1]
return dictionary

print(supermarket(prices1.csv))
```

However, when I debug the code, the traceback error says it is a NameError for which

> prices1

is not defined. My professor is telling me that my argument should be able to take prices1.csv as an argument but I don't see how that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually referring to a member `csv` of variable `prices1`, which obviously doesn't exist. Filename should actually be a string. So your code can be changed to this (assuming the csv file lies in the same directory as your working directory):

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv
import xlrd


def supermarket(filename):
    dictionary = {}
    with open(filename, newline='') as filename:
        read_csv = csv.reader(filename, delimiter=',')
        for row in read_csv:
            dictionary += row[0]
            dictionary[row[0]] = row[1]
    return dictionary

print(supermarket("prices1.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is convenience, use pandas library to handle CSV file in much more efficient way.